# Facebook Messenger Android Sdk Share setExternalUri

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have two URI's like.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+activity.getPackageName() +"/"+ R.drawable.tree);
Uri exuri = Uri.parse("https://cdn.xxx.com/slider/xxx.png");
```

And I set them with Facebook SDK;

```
ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(uri, "image/png").setExternalUri(exuri)
        .setMetaData("{ \"image\" : \"trees\" }")
        .build();
```

However First URI is required so I cannot share externalURI in anyway it always share the first URI. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content specified by the extends url must be exactly the same as the content specified by url.
I have found it in Android Facebook SDK source code.

```
An external URI that Messenger can use to download the content on Facebook's servers instead of requiring the Messenger application to upload the content. The content returned by the this URI must be exactly the same as the content specified by {@link #uri}. If the content is different, Messenger may fail to send the content. See <a href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android">developer docs</a> for more info.
```